# Finding Definite Integral where upper bound is variable

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

I believe my working out is correct but the answer I am obtained doesn't seem right:

Let

$$ xe^x = u.$$

Then
$$\frac{dF}{du} = \sin u^2 \,$$

But 
$$\frac{dF}{dx} = \frac{dF}{du} \frac{du}{dx}= \sin u^2  \frac{d}{dx} xe^x= (\sin (xe^x)^2) (e^x + xe^x).$$

Then do I just substitute $x=2$ and $x=-2$ into the fundamental theorem of calculus?

By doing so I obtain, $14.25$

Comment: Beware that $\sin u^2/ne(\sin u)^2$

Comment: @egreg i see, could you evaluate the integral so we can compare answers?

Answer (score 2):

The only error I find in your computation of the derivative is this:
\begin{align}
\text{wrong: } & \quad \frac{dF}{du} = \sin u^2 \, du \\[15pt]
\text{right: } & \quad \frac{dF}{du} = \sin u^2
\end{align}

Once you've found $\dfrac{dF}{dx}$ as a function of $x,$ you can evaluate it at $x=2$ just by evaluating it as $x=2.$

Comment: okay i understand that, thanks for the correction! so is 14.25 the correct integral by evaluating at $x=2$? if you could evaluate the integral from $x= -2 to x=2$ to compare answers that would be great!

Comment: computing the integral on my calculator gives ~1.6, where am i going wrong?